# Font Sizes and UIView Sizes are same for iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s,4s

Tags: iphone, swift, uiview, storyboard, uifont

The text size and buttons looks good on iPhone 7 and iPhone 6 but their size remain same when running on iPhone 5s or iPhone 5.

If I give a left space constraint of 15 points it looks really good on iPhone 7 but on iPhone 5s this give out too much space.

How to implement the dynamic views and FontSize for all families of devices.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what you've tried before, and what hasn't worked? See [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

For that you could user AutoLayout. Simply constrain your views to the margins of your superview. I.e.

```
yourView -> superView.Leading.Margin
yourView -> superView.Trailing.Margin
```

Using the margins of your view controller, you can ensure that it works well on all devices.

For the Font sizes- Apple provides you with something called 'preferredFontStyles' that you can use in almost all situations. So if you want your buttons to just have a normal looking text size on all devices, simply do this:

```
yourLabel.font = UIFont.preferredBody
```

or

```
UIFont.preferredTitle
```

etc etc.

Hope that helps to get the hang of it

Answer (score 0):

If, say, `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)` looks good for you on a 4.7" iPhone (where screen width is 375pt) , but too large on a a smaller device, you could try scaling the font based on the screen width…

```
let fontSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 375  * 16
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
```

For the insets, per @FlorensvonBuchwaldt, use Auto Layout to constrain your  `UILabel` to it's superview's margins, then set `layoutMargins` to a scaled inset…

```
let margin = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 375  * 15
myView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: margin, left: margin, bottom: margin, right: margin)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create global width ratio constant and use it when your need  
let _widthRatio : CGFloat = {
    let ratio = _screenSize.width/375
    return ratio
}()

//use constant 
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize * _widthRatio)

// if you set font from storyboard then create subclass of your control 
class YMWidthLabel: UILabel {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        font = font.withSize(font.pointSize * _widthRatio)
    }
}

// Now bind YMWidthLabel class in storyboard
```